# SetSafe Default Value in mgo session

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Can someone explain me the difference between the default value of `SetSafe()` which is `&Safe{}` and `SetSafe(nil)`?

As per the mgo [godoc](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.SetSafe):

> If the safe parameter is nil, the session is put in unsafe mode, and writes become fire-and-forget, without error checking. The unsafe mode is faster since operations won't hold on waiting for a confirmation.
>
> If the safe parameter is not nil, any changing query (insert, update, ...) will be followed by a getLastError command with the specified parameters, to ensure the request was correctly processed.
>
> The default is &Safe{}, meaning check for errors and use the default behavior for all fields.

Looking at the [code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/session.go#L1540) it seems it will call `getLastError` [command](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getLastError) in mongo with values `j:false, w:0, wtimeout:0`. This means it will not return any error from mongo and the behavior seems to be similar while calling `SetSafe(nil)`.

Then what error I am expected to receive while calling mongo with `SetSafe(&Safe{})`?

I am on Mongo 3.0.9.

Comment: *getLastError* is not a method, it's a struct look [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/session.go#L97). So he just fill the struct and return it, without check for any mongo error.

Comment: I know `getLastError` is a struct. The struct is stored in `cmd` as mentioned here :- http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/session.go#L1561. Then it seems it is calling the `getLastError` mongo command with values `j:false, w:0, wtimeout:0`.

Comment: When he set the *getLastError* with `safeOp == nil`, he also override the command in the struct with **1** instead of **getLastError**, line 1540

Comment: Yeah. It is setting the `cmd` in `s.safeOp` in the same function and then in `writeQuery` it is executing the command as shown [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/session.go#L3476)